# Regex to get string with complex structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a link look like:

```
var str = "http://example.com/ep-1-29838.html";
```

I want to get only **29838**

I tried with:

```
str = str.replace(^([-])\/([.html])$\w+, "");
```

I don't have many experiences with Regex. Thanks.

Comment: Does the filename always follow this structure?

Comment: @31piy of course. this filename always have the same structure

Comment: When the number always comes right before `.html` you can try this regex `([0-9]+)\.html`

Comment: @wayneOS good suggest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match the last digits followed by a dot and file extension:

```js
var str = "http://example.com/ep-1-29838.html";
console.log(
  str.match(/\d+(?=\.\w+$)/)
);
```

Comment: Your solution very smart!

Answer (score 1):

This could be an approach:

```
"http://example.com/ep-1-29838.html".match(/(\d+)\.html$/)
```

It basically means "match and store in a group one or more digit (0-9) that are followed by .html at the end of the string".

The value returned is an array of two element, you're interested in the second one.

Comment: Cool solution but get more step to get.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regex if it's this rigid - more readable to me like this:

```js
var str = "http://example.com/ep-1-29838.html";

str = str.split('-') /* split the string on hyphen */
        .pop() /* get last of generated array */
        .replace('.html', ''); /* now remove the file extension */

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Isn't it generally the other way around? It's nice to use regex if you can, but if you can't, then you have to resort to language-specific string manipulation

Comment: I like method `match` to resolve my problem. It special. Your solution is general in any case. Thanks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess all devs work in different ways - if there isn't s substantial performance loss (I haven't checked in this case but I doubt it), then readability wins every time for me.